# MySQL - Generate 40 Million Dummy Records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to fill the below table with 40 million dummy records:

`mysql> desc employees;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

I have no idea how this can be done in MySQL, I need help writing a script to do this.

Comment: Plain mysql, or are you using some other programming language like php?

Comment: https://www.mockaroo.com/ if it needs to be believable.

Comment: Plain MySQL, Mockaroo has a maximum limit of 1000.

Comment: http://www.generatedata.com/#generator

Comment: Ok once I have the CSV how do i import this into MySQL?